# PHP Regex: number x number

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex like for this pattern;

```
10x12
1x12
1x1
10x12
11x11
```

This is what i've found out, but its not working properly.

```
/([0-9]x[0-9])\w+/g
```

Comment: Try `/(\d+x\d+).*/` ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the numbers on the two sides have variable length. Therefore, change it to:

```
/([0-9]+x[0-9]+)/
```

`+` means repeat one or more times.

Comment: Thank you, this the thing ive been looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
/([0-9]{1,2}x[0-9]{1,2})/
```

`{1,2}` means that there can be from 1 to 2 numbers and not 0, 3 4 5, ...

Comment: @HakanYaman Please vote up my answer if it helped you. Thank you.