# Return xx characters before a certain string

Tags: php

So I have this string:

```
Best location using 168 cars + cleaning
```

The '168' is the part i'd like to extract from this string.

I have approximately 80 occurences of this string, all alternating from 'xx' cars to 'xxx' cars (so, 2 or 3 numbers). However, in each string, 'cars' comes after the number i'd like to return.

What would be the best way using PHP to achieve this?

Comment: You could split the string on whitespace, then search for the element `"cars"`, then grab the element before that. Example, if `"cars"` is at index `4`, the number you're seeking should be element `3`.

Comment: Take a look at the functions strpos and substr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516500/get-number-before-selected-word-form-string-using-preg-match-function-in-php try this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get number before selected word form string using preg\_match function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516500/get-number-before-selected-word-form-string-using-preg-match-function-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Regex: number x number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809900/php-regex-number-x-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to do a simple preg_match on the text.

See the tutorial: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
<?php
$string = 'Best location using 168 cars + cleaning';
$pattern = '/(\d{2,3}+) cars/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);

echo $match[1];
```

This regex returns all the numbers with length of 2 to 3 before the word cars.

you can change the length as you want and \d means all the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably via `preg_match()`. Look for a space, one or more digits, a space, then the word cars. Use parens to capture the digits. That gives you pattern like this:

```
' (\d+) cars'
```

Then just pass that to `preg_match()` with a third argument to capture the parenthesized substring:

```
if (preg_match('/ (\d+) cars/', $str, $match)) {
    echo "your num is: " . $match[1] . "\n";
}
```

Note this will also capture `1 cars` and `1234 cars`. If that's a problem, and you want to ensure that you only get the values with two or three digits, you can tweak the pattern to explicitly require that:

```
' (\d{2,3}) cars'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would explode the string on a space and then loop through the array looking for the string "cars" and then get the key value for this. From here you know that the number will be before the "cars" occurrence so minus 1 from this key value and look in the array.

```
$original_string = "Best location using 168 cars + cleaning";
$string = explode(" ", $original_string);
foreach ($string as $key => $part) {
    if($part == "cars") {
        $number = $string[$key-1];
    }
}
```

Explanation:
$original_string is whatever your whole string where the number is unknown.

$string is an array of the $original_string, each word will be in it's own part of the array

we loop through this array looking for the string "cars" and also get its key value.
If we find it successfully we then go to the key value minus one to find the number. We do this because we know the number appears before the "cars" string.

Comment: What if the original string is `This location has no cars`? :)

Comment: In this situation you won't get anything returned

Comment: I believe you'll find that you'll get "no" returned.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted what you meant. I thought you meant the string itself didn't contain cars. You are right that no would get returned but as Matthias said, cars comes before the number - assuming it is the first string after numbers the above example will always work